# html/php - format form text to html

Tags: php, mysql, html, textfield

I have this textfield in a html form, which I want to insert into my MySQL database using php.
But, I want the typed text to get HTML formatting, so I can easily display it on my website.
How can I do this?

The row where it should be inserted into the MySQL database is of the type: text.

The reason I want to know this, is because normally a textfield doesnt output linebreaks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IF you want to have the newlines, use the PHP function `nl2br()` so you will get the new lines.

If any HTML is typed into that box. you will get it.

However, I recommend not storing the `<br>` or `HTML tags you add manually` to the database, but do it later. The `nl2br()` function should be called after you get it from the database.

Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Ah, thanks!
That sounds great!
I didn't expect the solution to be this simple :P

Answer (score 5):

you can use this function to store in database

```
$a = htmlentities($orig);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

use this function when fetch data from database to show on page

```
$b = html_entity_decode($a);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Wow, I didn't need that function for this particular form, but damn, those function will definitly come in handy!
Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have the ability to create HTML using a WYSIWYG editor or will you hand type it in.  I would recommend FCK Editor, we use it on our site and it works great.

[CKEditor - WYSIWYG Editor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: No, I don't ;) I just need to add this functionality to a little upload form on my website [or better: the displaying of the messages, not the upload part, as Topener pointed out]
Though thank you for the link!